# How to only show documents where partition is equal to the user's ID in Realm?

Tags: mongodb, react-native, realm

Using realm, I want to ensure a user can only see documents created by them for security reasons. I add a _partition key to each document with the user's id as its value.

I currently do this to display transactions:

```js
const transactions = useQuery(Transaction, transaction => {
   return transaction.sorted('date')
})
```

However, this shows all existing transactions meaning anyone can see anyones transactions. I have explored MongoDB's docs but cannot see anything about it.

I am using realm in react native.

Comment: The question is a little vague and it's not clear what the code is for. If you want to only display documents "owned" by a user to the user, a query would be run against all documents where `_partitionKey == users id`. That query will return only that users documents. Is there something more?